# Admin verification of code after Contributor check in - TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

My company is currently in the process of moving to TFS 2018. We previously used a combination of SVN and Git to meet our needs but have now decided to move to TFS so that complete Application Development Cycle is performed on a single platform. And I have been asked to make this move.

The dev team has a requirement that once a Contributor checks in the code, it should not be automatically a part of Source code. Rather the team lead should first review the code checked in by the developer and approve or reject the changes made by the dev. I cannot see an option in TFS which we can use for the mentioned use case.

Any help?

Comment: "TFS" is not a version control system. TFS is a devops platform that supports two version control systems: Git and TFVC. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In Git:

Work in branches. Use pull requests with [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies-overview?view=azure-devops) to enforce code review prior to merge.

In TFVC:

There isn't a great code review mechanism, but there **is** a [code review mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=azure-devops). It creates shelvesets and uses special work item types called Code Review Request and Code Review Response to manage the code review process.